# How to rerun Airflow job if there has been a change in input data

Tags: airflow

**Situation**:

- I have an upstream job that reads events from a GCS replicated pub/sub topic(A), transforms them, and dumps the data in partitions based on event time.
- The next step of the pipeline involves matching the data with another stream of data(B) and constructing a funnel.
- It is possible that 5% of cases data[Topic A] can come delayed - say 3 hours.

**Task**:

- How do I rerun the funnel construction job for a specific hour whenever there has been a change in its input data[data coming delayed]?

I am aware such a requirement is supported in Apache Falcon. But I would like to know if it's supported natively in Airflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely. Airflow shines in this aspect.

Airflow has a "backfill" command that can be used for that very purpose.

All tasks of Airflow are supposed to be designed in the way that they are "idempotent" (so you can re-run them for a give interval and they should basically replace the data from the previous run of the same data interval).

Backfill can be used currently only using CLI-only (there are talks about bringing it to the UI as well).

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/cli-and-env-variables-ref.html#backfill

The nice thing about it that it will also trigger all subsequent, dependent tasks automatically, so Airflow does all the heavy-lifting to determine what needs to be re-run in case you decide to backfill just one task for some data intervals - it will re-run all the dependent tasks after that for those intervals as well.

Comment: My understanding is that `backfill` still requires one to manually trigger the command for the job (instance) - which would mean my producer job would need to be aware of downstream job[funnel builder - handled by a different team]. 

I was curious to see if Airflow provides a functionality on the lines of a 'listener' - given a path; Every time data changes Airflow automatically reruns the DAG instance depending on the data/folder.

Comment: Correct - bacfill is for manuall operation, but it can also be automated - you can easily run "backfill command" from the CLI as result of some trigger if your case requires it. In fact it could be easily done by .... another DAG that runs periodically or is triggered by some action. You can use BashOperator to run such backfill commands.

Comment: Thanks Jarek this answers my question. I prefer defining a separate 'notifier DAG' as suggested for separation of concerns.